# Searching for US Nebraska middle school literature texts from the 70's

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

When I was in 6th, 7th and 8th grade in mid-70's, my school used a series of textbooks for the literature classes.  I thought they were excellent collections and I've hunted for them several times over the last decade.  I remember a few of the stories, but don't remember which of the 3 texts each particular story came from, which makes the search harder.  Here's the stories I remember:

- "The Strangers that Came to Town" by Ambrose Flack.
- The scene from "The Hobbit" where Bilbo is riddling with Gollum.
- "The Boy Who Painted Christ Black" by John Henrik Clarke.

I can try to describe the cover art, as I remember it.  The 6th-grade text had an abstract painting done with earth tones on a white background.  The paint was real thick and globby.  The image looked vaguely like a loaf of bread with on slice cut off and lying in front of it.  The 7th grade text again had a white background but the painting was even more abstract.  Black streaks and splotches.

I'm good at Google; really good. But nothing.  E-bay has a huge collection of middle school texts.  Nothing.  I don't remember the publisher, but Houghton-Mifflin seemed to be the publisher for most of our texts back then and their website gives me nothing.  Now that I finally have a grandson, I'd like to add these to my collection of all the books I'm going to read to him.  Any leads or a better place to ask are welcome.

Comment: I was going to ask where that painting-Christ-black story was set, but now you found the title of that one :-D (In many parts of Christian Africa, the established church teaching is that Christ was black, so this wouldn't be anything out of the ordinary.)

Comment: Which country is this?

Comment: @muru   U.S.   Nebraska, to be specific.